# Collect data only for odd positions

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I have data set, say,

`list={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3},{x4,y4},...,{xn,yn}}`

How can I construct the following list  ?

`list2= {{x1,y1},{x3,y3},{x5,y5},{x7,y7}...}`

Comment: `list = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}, {x5, y5}, {x6, 
    y6}, {x7, y7}};
list[[;; ;; 2]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list2 = list[[;; ;; 2]]
```

array[[i;;j;;k ]]
represents a span from **i** through **j** in steps of **k**. and,

array[[;;;;k ]]
represents a span from the **beginning** to the **end** in steps of **k**.

Comment: This answer is the same as the comment by @cvgmt.